# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'response_class'

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I am trying to write some basic tests for my flask application using pytest.
My Folder Structure looks like that:

```
root/
    |- app.py
    |- conftest.py
    |- tests/
        |- test_app.py
```

This is my flask application:

```
from flask import Flask, request, send_file


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world(): 
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my conftest.py, which is used for fixtures. This is from the flask documentation with some changes, since I do not use an create_app() function.

```
@pytest.fixture()
def app():
    yield app


@pytest.fixture()
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()


@pytest.fixture()
def runner(app):
    return app.test_cli_runner()
```

This is my test_app.py:

```
from app import app
import pytest


def test_request(client):
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.get_data() == "Hello World"
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

However, when I run pytest, I get the following error message (short summary at the bottom):

```
__________________ ERROR at setup of test_request ___________________

request = <SubRequest '_monkeypatch_response_class' for <Function test_request>>
monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x00000275AA8426B0>

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def _monkeypatch_response_class(request, monkeypatch):
        """Set custom response class before test suite and restore the original
        after. Custom response has `json` property to easily test JSON responses::

            @app.route('/ping')
            def ping():
                return jsonify(ping='pong')

            def test_json(client):
                res = client.get(url_for('ping'))
                assert res.json == {'ping': 'pong'}

        """

        if "app" not in request.fixturenames:
            return

        app = getfixturevalue(request, "app")
        monkeypatch.setattr(
>           app, "response_class", _make_test_response_class(app.response_class)
        )
E       AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'response_class'

..\x\lib\site-packages\pytest_flask\plugin.py:82: AttributeError

===================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR src/tests/test_app.py::test_request - AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'response_class'
```

Comment: The `app` you've imported is a function that returns the `app` object.  You would need `app().response_class()`.

Comment: Removing the import app solved the issue